# php - how to convert ascii png response to an actual image

Tags: php

I've used android-market-api-php to receive screenshot of google play apps but when I receive an app, in the response I get a long data that looks like that:

"?PNG\r\n\u001A\N\u0000",...and it goes on

How do I convert it to an actual Image that I can show on a web page?

Comment: Output it and put a `header("Content-type: image/png");` in front of it

Comment: try this [official wiki](https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api-php/wiki/HowToGetAppScreenshot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need an *actual image object* (which you can process via PHP), you can use [`imagecreatefromstring`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php) from the [GD extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php). 
You can then output the (processed) image to the browser - for example via [`imagepng`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php).

If you only want to save the file, use [`file_put_contents('filename.png', $png_as_string);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).

Comment: I would like to save it to an actual file

Comment: @Alon: `file-put-contents` is probably the simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

If it is sent with proper headers it will be displayed by the browser as an image. You can also save it to a file or create your own response with a proper `Content-Type` header and send it to the browser.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I create a file from it ?

Comment: @Alon dump the string to a file